# AngularJS2: NgFor template inside Template is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, primeng

***UPDATE*: This a bug in Angular <=2.4.1. See my "proof" posting below.**

I have a problem with AngularJS (2.2) with For loop templates inside templates to display an array inside an array.

See the MWE below. The first picture shows the start situation, If you press the button once, I get the desired output, however if I press the button again I get strange output (FIELD: 2 SUBFIELD: 2 expected)

**It seems that the for loop does not work correctly anymore once initialized. How can I fix this?**

If I remove the inner-For template, I get the desired output for only FIELD again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**MWE**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';  
import {Button,DataList} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template: `<button (click)="refreshData(dlist)">Press Me</button>
        <p-dataList #dlist  [value]="dataItems" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" [totalRecords]="totalRecords"> 
      <header>Run {{run}}</header>
      <template let-dataItem> 
        FIELD: {{dataItem.field}}
        <template ngFor let-n [ngForOf]="dataItem.array">  
            SUBFIELD: {{n.item}}
        </template>
      </template>
    </p-dataList>`
})

export class AppComponent  { 
    dataItems : DataItem[];
    totalRecords : number;
    run : number;

    constructor() { 
        this.run = 0;
    }
    loadData(event : any ) { 
    }
    refreshData(dtree : any ) { 
        this.run++;
        var json = "{ \"data\": [{\"field\": \""+this.run+"\", \"array\" : [{ \"item\": \""+this.run+"\"}]}]}";
        console.log(json);
        this.dataItems = <DataItem[]> JSON.parse(json).data; 
        // force paginator back to first page. 
        dtree.paginate({ first: 0 , rows: dtree.rows});
    }
}

export interface DataItem {
    array : MyValue[];
    field: String;
} 

export interface MyValue { 
    item : String;
}
```

Comment: can you create a plunkr?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Plunker. I posted the solution myself:it is a bug in Angular fixed in 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<template *ngFor="let item of dataItem.array">  
        SUBFIELD: {{item.item}}
</template>
```

Comment: No this does not work. After the button press you get "FIELD 1"  (so without SUBFIELD) and the second button press you get "SUBFIELD [Object, Object]"  so now FIELD is entirely missing, and SUBFIELD looks like an array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. This is a bug in AngularJS <=2.4.1. This [Plunker snippet](https://embed.plnkr.co/VdgOExNwVpiejYedJkC8/)
demonstrates the problem. Click multiple times on the button, to see the effect.

If you copy/fork the snippet and change the Angualar version in this Plunker snippet by changing `systemjs.config.js`:

`var V =   '2.4.1';`

to

`var V =   '2.4.2';`

You see that clicking multiple times on the button now produces the desired effect, without other modifications.

However, I could not find in the Angular 2 change log the related bug. However there are some fixes reported related to templates/ngFor.